# Web Deploy and Microsoft Azure ApplicationInsights

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, azure-application-insights

I have an on premise IIS instance that I publish to using web deploy. When I added Application Insights I get the following error.

```
(Unable to perform the operation ("Delete File")  for the specified directory
("Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x64.dll").
```

If I try to delete the file manually it says it is in use by the IIS Worker Process. Is there any way to reset the site or override the lock so that it can successfully publish? Or is there a way to not publish this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SDK 0.12 the only workaround is to stop application pool which your web site is running on before running deployment, so locked modules will be unloaded and deployment procedure will be able to rewrite file(s).

And yes, this issue is prioritized to be fixed in 0.13.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue and fixed is being worked on. We plan to deploy the fix with the next version of SDK release (0.13).

Comment: Is there any link where from we could check whether the fix made into the release?

Comment: Nuget package usually has release notes. But you would see things like API change, or some feature was added. List of bugs is not available. As far as I know fix for your issue was included in 0.13 so try to upgrade.